# Does Microsoft Exchange 2010 have two kinds of Distribution Groups?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I was told to add someone to a Distribution Group and when I ran:

```
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

from Exchange Management Shell I didn't the desired distribution group in the list.

Comment: My first thought is, "Ask your Exchange admin to add a person to a distribution group". When you open EMC, do you see the distribution group in question?

Comment: I do but that doesn't answer my question about powershell.

Comment: Oh I see it's a MsExchDynamicDistributionList

Comment: Yes, that's the other kind of DL. Static and Dynamic.

Comment: @leeand00 - you should probably just delete this question now.

Comment: In your original question, you didn't ask how to do it with powershell.

Comment: @DanBig fair enough.

Comment: Also, to clarify (forgive my being pendantic) but Exchange doesn't call them `mailing lists`. They're called `Distribution Groups`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still running Exchange 2007, but I don't believe this part has changed...  There are two different types of Distribution Groups in Exchange:

1. "Standard" Distribution Groups
2. Dynamic Distribution Groups

A "Standard" Distribution Group is basically just a group where you've added either other groups (Dynamic or "Standard") or individual users (Mailboxes, Contacts, etc.).  The powershell cmdlet `Get-DistributionGroup` will work on these types of groups.

A Dynamic Distribution Group is built using rules so that it basically generates the recipient list every time a message is sent.  You need to use the `Get-DynamicDistributionGroup` powershell cmdlet to work with these groups.